# Admin generator - visible or not action

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

```
config:
  list:
    object_actions:
      extend:     ~
      _edit:      ~
      _delete:    ~
```

Is possible to show action extend only if in database in this same record is set field **visible** on 1?

For example:

```
config:
  list:
    object_actions:
      extend:     if(this.status == 1 then SHOW else if (this.status == 0) then NOT SHOW
      _edit:      ~
      _delete:    ~
```

in database i have for example:

```
id | name | extend | visible
1  | aaa  |  0     | 0          
2  | bbb  |  0     | 1
3  | ccc  |  0     | 1
4  | aaa  |  0     | 0
5  | bbb  |  0     | 1
6  | ccc  |  0     | 1
```

so if visible == 1 then should show me action extend in admin generator

Comment: Has my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you can overwrite any template auto-generated. Maybe it's not the best way, but that trick may be helpful many times.

Just browse the backend cache generated templates, copy to the template folder of your module and change whatever you want.

For example, assuming that your entity's name is "**Entity**", copy

*cache/backend/dev/modules/auto **Entity**/templates/_list_td_actions.php*

to your

*apps/backend/modules/**entity**/templates* folder.

As you can see, in that file there's a **$entity** var to add your logic.